# How To Create a Map of Vowel Combinations from Words in a Text File

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to aggregate vowel combinations of the words in a text file using Scala. For example if the text file was: 
"This is a text file."

The output would be something like
(i,2)
(a,1)
(e,1)
(ei,1)

I am brand new to spark/scala so please forgive my ignorance.

My current code:

```
val wordsFile = sc.textFile("test.txt");
val flattenMap = wordsFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
```

I've made a small vowel function to check each char, but I'm unsure how to properly implement it.

```
def isVowel(letter: Char): Boolean = {
letter match {
case 'a' => true;
case 'e' => true;
case 'i' => true;
case 'o' => true;
case 'u' => true;
case _ => false;
}
```

How might I iterate over each word in flattenMap and store the vowels in a new map? 
Thank you.

Comment: can you explain the output (ei,1)?

Comment: The last word "file" contains vowels 'e' and 'i'.

Comment: then you can also say it contains (ie, 1) can't you? please see my answer below if it answers yours question

Comment: I can see that the vowels need to be in alphabetical order rather than the order in the word, but can you clarify what should happen if there are two of the same vowel in a word? Do "the" and "there" have the same "vowel combination" or is one "e" and the other "ee"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > How To Create a Map of Vowel Combinations from Words in a Text File

All you need to do is *replace the consonants with space* and you will be *left with combinations of vowels* and then just use `reduceByKey` *to count* them.

```
val wordsFile = sc.textFile("test.txt")
val flattenMap = wordsFile
                    .flatMap(line => line.toLowerCase.replaceAll("[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]", " ").split(" "))
                    .filter(_ != "")
                    .map((_, 1))
                    .reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

**NOTE: the solution counts the exact combination of vowels in whole text so you can modify according to your combination requirements**

so if you have input as

```
This is a text file teefie
```

the output would be

```
(ee,1)
(e,2)
(a,1)
(i,3)
(ie,1)
```

**Updated**

Looking at your expected output as

> > The output would be something like (i,2) (a,1) (e,1) (ei,1)

following modification should give the result

```
val wordsFile = sc.textFile("test.txt")
val flattenMap = wordsFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" ").map(_.toLowerCase.replaceAll("[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz.,]", "").sorted))
                    .filter(_ != "")
                    .map((_, 1))
                    .reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

which should give you following output for the input `This is a text file.`

```
(e,1)
(a,1)
(i,2)
(ei,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `groupBy`, which groups data according a key computed from each data value.

```
val text = "This is a text file."

def vowels(s: String) = s.replaceAll("[^aeiou ]", "").sorted

text
  .trim.split("\\s+")
  .groupBy(vowels)
  .collect{ case(k, v) => (k, v.length) }
```

The `vowels` function extracts the vowels from a word. This version sorts the vowels but does not combine multiple instances of the same vowel. Replace this with the exact operation that you want. This can be any function that extracts the important characteristics from a word.

`trim` and `split` breaks the text into words separated by spaces.

`groupBy` groups the words according to the result of `vowels`.

`collect` converts the list generated by `groupBy` into a count.

The result is a `Map[String, Int]` but use `toList` if you need a `List` rather than a `Map`.

#### Update to handle upper-case vowels

If you need to handle upper-case vowels there are three possible routes.

1) Convert the string at the start

```
.trim.toLowerCase.split("\\s+")
```

This is potentially more efficient, but it is perhaps it is more logical to put rules about the case of vowels in the `vowels` check

2) Convert the string in `vowels`

```
def vowels(s: String) = s.toLowerCase.replaceAll("[^aeiou ]", "").sorted
```

3) Add upper-case vowels to the pattern

```
def vowels(s: String) = s.replaceAll("[^AaEeIiOoUu ]", "").sorted
```

This preserves the case of the vowels which may or may not be what is wanted.